# Inserting hyperlinks into pdf generated with pisa

Tags: python, django, pisa

Currently I am generating a pdf from a html template in django/python.

Here is a relevant snipit from my view

```
result = StringIO.StringIO()
html = render_to_string(template='some_ref/pdf.html', { dictionary passed to template},)
pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html), dest=result) 
return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
```

And my template is an html file that I would like to insert a hyperlink into. Something like

```
 <td style="padding-left: 5px;">
     <a href="/something_here/?referral_type={{ template_variable }}">{{ some_other_variable }}</a>
 </td>
```

Actually, the pdf generates fine and the template variables are passed correctly and show in the pdf. What is inside the `a` tag is highlighted in blue and underlined as if you could click on it, but when I try to click on it, the link is not followed. I have seen pdfs before with clickable links, so I believe it can be done.

Is there a way I can do this to make clickable hyperlinks on my pdf using pisa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works with the complete url: http protocol and domain

```
<a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/something_here/?referral_type={{ template_variable }}">{{ some_other_variable }}</a>
```

Comment: Strange to me that the full url is needed in this particular instance, but I believe you are absolutely correct.